# JavaScript generated code and screen readers

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, wcag2.0

I'm asking you to help me out, I'm totally stuck with this problem.

I want to make possible my code to be navigated through keyboard and adoptable to screen reader devices. But I have several issues.

This is my code in JS:

```
function changeText()
{
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input id="btn2" type="button" onclick="changeText2()" value="Change Text2" />';
 document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute("aria-hidden",true);
 document.getElementById('div1').focus();
}
function changeText2()
{
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input id="btn3" type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="Change Text" />';
 document.getElementById('btn1').setAttribute("aria-hidden",true);
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
<input id="btn1" type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
</div>
```

when I navigate to `btn1` in windows with keyboard only(with tab) and then press enter(or space) the button is changed, but it lose focus. As you may see, I tried to focus it with JS, but without a result. I also tried to use `tabindex` tag, but didn't help too. I want it to be focused when it is pressed, so it will be easier to navigate and to be accessible for screen readers.

Please help!

### EDIT

Focus has been tested on the button with James Long solution and it works!

However, the `btn.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);` should be removed.

### Final EDIT

I just got it, lol! In order to MY example to work properly, I have should be focus to `btn2` instead of `btn1`. This is so silly! So, it goes as follows:

```
function changeText()
{
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input id="btn2" type="button" onclick="changeText2()" value="Change Text2" />';
 document.getElementById('btn2').focus();
}
function changeText2()
{
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input id="btn1" type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="Change Text" />';
 document.getElementById('btn1').focus();
}
```

I feel proud of my self :)

Comment: I don't see the point of setting `aria-hidden` attribute to true if you want the button to be accessible to a screen reader.

Comment: To Adam, I did it for the `btn1` while `btn2` is displayed. Because I don't really know if screen reader will read the default(hard-coded) `btn1` with `btn2`(or `btn3`) that is generated by JS. But in James Long answer there is 'aria-hidden', it's not critical I think, because even I can understand it should be deleted(and I'm new :) )  To Alteyss, how is it you're able to edit my question? If the focus is not working to you, please consider to edit your answer below, because the answer of James Long has focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a screen reader to hand so it's tricky to test this, but you might have better luck changing a button rather than replacing it and focussing on the button itself.

```
<div id="div1">
    <button type="button" id="btn1">Change Text</button>
</div>
```

And then your JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    function changeText(btn) {

        btn.textContent = btn.textContent === 'Change Text'
            ? 'Change Text2'
            : 'Change Text';
        btn.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
        btn.focus();

    }

    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        changeText(e.target);
    }, false);

}, false);
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so it will work, because I tried it and it didn't. Also, tried to play with it, didn't help much. Text not changing

Comment: @jfanderson - OK, try that. I've put it into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/aqcL2e4s/) so you can see it working

Comment: THANK YOU! :)  Working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Put the focus on your button :

```
$("#btn1").focus();
```

In pure JS :

```
document.getElementById('btn1').focus();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I tried this. I tried it with lots of variation, like instead of btn1, the btn2(relatively), but no result.